# report builder for non SQL users

Tags: sql, user-interface

Rather than have users try to write their own SQL queries is there a drag and drop tool that could sorta build the SQL queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Sql Server, Take a look at reporting services ... there are some facilities to support end users creating simple ad-hoc reports.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many available.
http://www.activedbsoft.com/overview-querytool.html